# Rails app claims to successfully send email but never completes task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm working on a Rails app which should send a confirmation email when a new user registers.

My mailer looks like this:

```
def notify_email(volunteer)
    @volunteer= volunteer
    @admin = Volunteer.first
    mail(to: @admin.email, subject: 'New Application from ' + volunteer.first_name+ '!', body: 
'You have new applicants, please go check on your admin dashboard!

You can contact ' + @volunteer.first_name+ ' at: ' +@volunteer.email+ '.')

  end
end
```

In my production.rb file I have email configurations set as follows(gmail username/password replaced with x's):

```
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:8080' }

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => "587",
    :domain => "gmail.com",
    :user_name => 'xxxxxx', 
    :password => 'xxxxxxx',
    :authentication => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

My controller has this code:

```
def create
    @admin= Volunteer.first
    @volunteer = Volunteer.create(volunteer_params)
    @volunteer.save
    if @volunteer.save
            flash[:success] = "Successfully Registered!"        

            #email notifes admin of new registration
        NotifyMailer.notify_email(@volunteer).deliver_now

        redirect_to '/volunteer'
    end
```

And finally when I test the app on the local server the console gives me this information(emails x'ed out again):

```
NotifyMailer#notify_email: processed outbound mail in 1.5ms
Sent mail to xxxx@xxxx.org (2004.5ms)
Date: Sun, 06 Jan 2019 16:04:49 -0600
From: xxxxxxx@gmail.com
To: xxxxx@xxxxx.org
Message-ID: <5c327b817c32e_3de83ca21e89202@LAPTOP-N2MQ7EL0.mail>
Subject: New Application from Rachel!
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Can anyone give me insight into what I'm missing? I've checked several forums and threads and it seems like I'm following the right steps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question - you can't send email in dev or prod env? For dev - use MailCatcher/LetterOpener/etc (you shouldn't really send emails in dev env). For prod - [allow less secure apps access your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Comment: in your production environment it is working?

Comment: @Vasilisa It must have been the 2-step authentication and access for less secure apps. It is functional now. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @dbate, happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Unable to comment, but what happens if you call

```
NotifyMailer.notify_email(@volunteer).deliver
```

instead of

```
NotifyMailer.notify_email(@volunteer).deliver_now
```

I believe deliver_now relays on a background worker like sidekiq,
plus try the
[gem "letter_opener"](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) which will open a new tab in your browser to check your emails.